# build.xml fx:association throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx, build, ant, file-association

I want to associate my JavaFX (JDK1.8.0_231) Application with certain files to run automatically.

The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/selfContainedApps/fileassociation.html) says to put an `<fx:association>` tag inside of the `<fx:info>` tag. I was able to build the application before adding the tag.

This is the ant build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Busfahrplan" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\Temp\Documents\Eclipse-workspaces\Java\Busfahrplan\lib">
            <filename name="gson-2.8.5.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\Temp\Documents\Eclipse-workspaces\Java\Busfahrplan">
            <include name="test/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="C:\Users\Temp\Documents\Eclipse-workspaces\Java\Busfahrplan">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="gson-2.8.5.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/test">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="utf-8">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/test">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>

</target>

<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="Busfahrplan.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="Busfahrplan"
        mainClass="application.Main"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />

<fx:jar destfile="dist/Busfahrplan.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="com.test.Busfahrplan"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="Busfahrplan"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
        <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
     </manifest>
 </fx:jar>


 <mkdir dir="deploy" />

 <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="Busfahrplan" nativeBundles="exe"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231"/>
        <fx:info title="Busfahrplan" vendor="com.test.Busfahrplan">
            <!--<fx:association extension="bfd" description="Busfahrplan File" />-->
        </fx:info>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>
  </target>
</project>
```

If I deploy with comment that Line out, the compiler throws a Nullpointer Exception

```
do-deploy:
        [copy] Copying 8 files to C:\Users\Temp\Documents\Eclipse-workspaces\Java\Busfahrplan\build\dist\libs
       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Temp\Documents\Eclipse-workspaces\Java\Busfahrplan\build\build\classes\META-INF
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre

Running [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\bin\java, -version]
Running [C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6\iscc.exe, /?]
  Detected [C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6\iscc.exe] version [6]
Running [C:\Users\Temp\AppData\Local\Temp\iconswap993666012502793725.exe, C:\Users\Temp\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler4340850078134818070\windows\Busfahrplan.ico, C:\Users\Temp\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler4340850078134818070\images\win-exe.image\Busfahrplan\Busfahrplan.exe]

Bundler EXE Installer failed because of java.lang.NullPointerException
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 6 seconds
```

The Application builded but without any file associations. Notice that it took only 6 seconds where normally it was around a minute.

I also want to add an icon to all created bfd files. But adding the tag "icon" to the fx:association node does not work. I have put the .ico in the /dist folder.

Comment: Please enable verbose by -v then attached same logs

Comment: If you can't get this to work, you could try upgrading to a Java 14 early access release and use the [jpackage tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) to package your application.  That tool documentation states that it can set file associations and icons for applications, which are requirements you list in your question.

Comment: @Sarjit Thanks! Edited Question and pasted verbose prints between using and the exception. The icon is at build/package/windows